# set a value in a new column using the entries in two column in a single row

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in a database table, `id, location_A, location_B`

```
id    location_A     location_B
1        ROOM 1         ROOM 2
2        ROOM 2         ROOM 3
3        ROOM 5         MEETING ROOM
```

Now I would like to add a new column name Length something as below the value will be added in the query like

```
case when LOCATION_A='ROOM 1' AND LOCATION_B='ROOM 2' THEN 6
     when LOCATION_A='ROOM 2' AND LOCATION_B='ROOM 3' THEN 8
```

and so on

```
id    location_A     location_B            length
1        ROOM 1         ROOM 2                6
2        ROOM 2         ROOM 3                8
3        ROOM 5         MEETING ROOM          50
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the length value calculation?

Comment: I would like to fill the length coloumn with the actual distance between two room using sql query

Answer (score 1):

You can use that `CASE WHEN` statement in `UPDATE` query this way :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET length = 
      (case 
         when LOCATION_A='ROOM 1' AND LOCATION_B='ROOM 2' THEN 6
         when LOCATION_A='ROOM 2' AND LOCATION_B='ROOM 3' THEN 8
         else 50
       end)
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76394/5)**

**UPDATE :**

Microsoft Access version of above SQL :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET length = 
    switch(
        LOCATION_A='ROOM 1' AND LOCATION_B='ROOM 2', 6
        , LOCATION_A='ROOM 2' AND LOCATION_B='ROOM 3', 8
        , true, 50)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error msg  [microsoft]{odbc microsoft access driver}Too few parameters. Expected 1. CODE 3010 SQLSTATE 07001

Comment: so you're using ms access, aren't you? should've mentioned that from the beginning.

Comment: PLS can u ckeck the below sql for microsoft access can it made compactUPDATE MASTER_SCHEDULE
SET CABLE_LENTH = 
    switch(
          RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 1', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 2' AND RACK_B='RK 2', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 3' AND RACK_B='RK 3', 6
      and so on about more 20 conditions length for all will be 6
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 2' OR RACK_A = 'RK 2' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',6.5
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 3' OR RACK_A = 'RK 3' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',7
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 4' OR RACK_A = 'RK 4' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',7.5
and so on
  , true, 0)

Comment: I'm not going to continue discussion here. Post new question and describe what you are after there. Posting unformatted SQL/codes in comment, adding requirement on the go. Bad attitude makes people less eager to help.

Comment: i will post a new question for the same

Answer (score 0):

If the logic for that **length** calculation is actually based on the actual data in **location_A** and **location_B** you can do:

- create a view and simply add **length** as a calculated column
- add a new column to the table and the Update it using your calculation

Comment: The above case statement does not seem to work can any one send a full sql

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" mean? The above CASE needs an END of course. Otherwise **you** should post your actual CASE statement.

Comment: Also the length is predetermined by the entries in both the column and not by a single column i.e (ROOM 1 to ROOM 2 =6)each indiviual column does not have any value.i want to add distance between room1 and room2

Comment: Depnding on the number of locations this might result in a huge CASE, but there's no restriction on the the number of WHENs.